# Not the same alfresco query results in different browsers

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, authentication, networking, alfresco

I have the weirdest problem.
I wrote a webscript in Alfresco that searches the number of documents matching a criteria.

If I call it from Chrome / IE, the results are right : a number around 6 / 10 documents.

If I call it from Firefox on my machine, the number is totally wrong ( 250 as I limit it to 250) but if I call it from another it's alright.

I have no clue as to what causes this. I uninstalled completely Firefox, checked the networks settings in FF, on the network cards, firewalls,... The calls seems identical through Fiddler.

The calls are not made using SSO. I use the /s/ calls. I get a prompt where I give my username / password.

I have no clue as to find what is wrong with those machines...

Comment: could you please share the query you are running, and possibly the dump of the HTTP request as captured by Firebug?

Comment: var from = new Date(new Date().getTime() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
  var query = 'EXACTTYPE:"cm:content" AND @cm\\:modified:[' + utils.toISO8601(from) + ' TO MAX]';
  var nodes =  search.luceneSearch(query);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So which version of Alfresco are you using? Maybe this is related to some pecularities when querying with different language settings, see for example

https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/ALF-7691

for an issue i had some time ago.

Comment: Our installation of Alfresco 3.4.11 is in French. I use the english version of Firefox. Once changed to the french version of FF, it works !!!! Is that something of a bug ??

Comment: Strange that it makes any difference in your case, as the query you use does not do any text search where this misbehaviour may apply (scratching head)?!

Comment: @Vincent Some properties in alfresco data model can have a multi-language type, meaning if your Firefox is in French, it will search, create stuff in french. Then you come with, say, Chrome, and it's in English - it will search in the english subset and find nothing. That could be your problem.

Comment: When in english it doesn't find "nothing", it finds "everything" ! I would have agreed with your point if nothing was retrieved.